# Quartz - Unable to restart scheduler

Tags: tomcat, quartz-scheduler, turbine

I have a legacy web application using quartz 1.5.0, wraped using [fulcrum](https://turbine.apache.org/fulcrum/fulcrum-quartz/).

After a system crash, when restarting Apache tomcat (hosting the application) I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Trigger with name: 'xxx' and group: 'yyy', because one already exists with this identification.
at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.storeTrigger(RAMJobStore.java:309)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:652)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249)
at org.apache.fulcrum.quartz.impl.DefaultQuartzScheduler.initialize(DefaultQuartzScheduler.java:170)
at org.apache.fulcrum.yaafi.framework.container.ServiceComponentImpl.initialize(ServiceComponentImpl.java:280)
at org.apache.fulcrum.yaafi.framework.container.ServiceContainerImpl.incarnate(ServiceContainerImpl.java:472)
at org.apache.fulcrum.yaafi.framework.container.ServiceContainerImpl.incarnate(ServiceContainerImpl.java:522)
at org.apache.fulcrum.yaafi.framework.container.ServiceContainerImpl.initialize(ServiceContainerImpl.java:201)
at org.apache.fulcrum.yaafi.framework.factory.ServiceManagerFactory.create(ServiceManagerFactory.java:141)
at org.apache.turbine.services.yaaficomponent.TurbineYaafiComponentService.init(TurbineYaafiComponentService.java:194)
... 13 more
```

Quartz configuration (file quartz.properties):

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

As far as I can understand, quartz schedule is stored in RAM. Right?

Question 1: I have tried to restart tomcat, and even the whole virtual machine. Why does the error persist? I suppose the RAM should be cleared and everything should be restarted.

Question 2: Supposing that I miss something, where could the quartz jobs be stored? I looked in the system's database but I could not find anything relevant.

Question 3: Could I somehow enforce quartz to restart without changing the app code?

Please note that this is a legacy web application which I don't even have the source code of.

Comment: Apparently, your application tries to add the same trigger twice. The fastest way to find out why is to run your app in a debugger, place a breakpoint in StdScheduler.java on line 249 and see where it is called from and why it is called twice for the same trigger (i.e. same trigger key).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your comment. This application is running in 4 instances/setups for more than 10 years and it's the first time this thing happens. It happens only in one of the four instances and it happened after a crash where I had to manually restart everything.

Indeed, debugging would be the most appropriate thing to do. However, debugging would require for me to reverse engineer the whole binary software stack which as you understand is far from trivial. If we leave this option aside, could you please suggest something for my questions?

Comment: What happens when you try to start your application instances one by one? Do you also get the error? With JDBC job store, I would say it is a race condition, but with a RAM job store, it must be a bug in your app. If you do not have sources of your app, then it is definitely not quite trivial to debug this, but at least you can find out the origin of the scheduleJob call.

Comment: All the other instances work fine. I will try to disactivate quartz scheduler by changing the properties file. Hopefully, then the application would work or I will see another error which might guide me somehow. Thank you for your time and the insights.

Comment: I wonder whether there could be some "temp file" or "cache file" stored somewhere (perhaps by Tomcat application server) which could restore a crashed memory status where a job is already there and my application tries to restore it

Comment: No, the RAM job store is not backed by a temp file of any kind. Everything is stored in RAM only.